# FlatList optimisation

Tags: reactjs, react-native

**FlatList optimization:**

Should I wrap all functions passed in `FlatList` in `useCallback()` hook ?

From the official doc

https://reactnative.dev/docs/optimizing-flatlist-configuration#avoid-anonymous-function-on-renderitem

described about using `useCallback` only for:

```
renderItem={renderItem}

keyExtractor={keyExtractor}
```

but I wonder should I wrap `getItemLayout` and `listHeaderComponent` also:

```
 <FlatList
    
    data={uiStore.data}
    
    ref={flatListRef}
    
    getItemLayout={getItemLayout}
    
    ListHeaderComponent={listHeaderComponent}
    
    renderItem={renderItem}
    
    keyExtractor={keyExtractor}
    
    />
```

I wan't to increase performance of my app

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap `getItemLayout` but there wont be any crucial performance gain and it may cause incorrect layout.

Avoid anonymous function means you should not pass arrow functions `()=>({})`

```js
 <FlatList
    data={uiStore.data}
    ref={flatListRef}
    getItemLayout={getItemLayout}
    ListHeaderComponent={listHeaderComponent}
    renderItem={(item)=> renderItem(item)} // avoid this
    keyExtractor={keyExtractor}
 />
```

Answer (score 0):

The decision to use `useCallback` for functions like `getItemLayout` and `ListHeaderComponent` in a `FlatList` component depends on whether these functions have dependencies that might trigger unnecessary re-renders.

The key takeaway from the official documentation is to avoid anonymous functions in `renderItem` and `keyExtractor` because creating new functions on each render can cause unnecessary re-renders of child components. This advice is specifically focused on the `renderItem` function, which is called for each item in the list and can significantly impact performance if not memoized.